# bash - jq iterating over json with spaces in key and value

Tags: json, bash, dynamic, jq

Trying to iterate the top level keys and corresponding json object value from a file with following structure.

```
{
   "parkey1":{
      "parkey1subkey1":"sub val1",
      "parkey1subkey2":"sub val2"
   },
   "parkey2":{
      "parkey2subkey1":{
         "subsubkey1":"val with space",
         "subsubkey2":{
            "subsubval3":"val space"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The above structure is just a sample. The keys and values can be anything. The expected output is to get the keys and corresponding json object values. With to_entries the spaces between the string values are breaking the logic.

Desired output:

```
key: "parkey1"
value: {
      "parkey1subkey1":"sub val1",
      "parkey1subkey2":"sub val2"
   }

key: parkey2
value: {
      "parkey2subkey1":{
         "subsubkey1":"val with space",
         "subsubkey2":{
            "subsubval3":"val space"
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: @Tuxinose, Are you saying its not possible with jq at all..

Comment: It *is* possible. Ignore comments like that one

Comment: Can you show *how* to_entries and spaces are breaking the logic?

Comment: It's possible, but generating non-JSON output is simpler in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
jq 'to_entries[]' | sed -e 's/^[{}]//' -e 's/^  //'
```

If the quotes around the top-level `key` and `value` tokens are an issue, you can easily extend the sed directives based on the uniform indentation.